# I am Trying to fetch data from firebase and getting null value in snapshot

Tags: flutter, dart

**I have debug my code and getting data in model class but in ui side its not reflecting and getting null value on snapshot.data
Will someone help me I stuck here from last 2 days**

**Model Class**

```
 class QuestionsModel {
  String question;
  String askTheExpert;
  String correctAnswer;
  String optA;
  String optB;
  String optC;
  String optD;
  String prize;

  QuestionsModel(
      {required this.question,
      required this.askTheExpert,
      required this.correctAnswer,
      required this.optA,
      required this.optB,
      required this.optC,
      required this.optD,
      required this.prize});
}
```

**Data source**

```
class QuestionDataSource {
  final random = Random();

  Future<QuestionsModel?> fetchQuestionModel({String? quizId, int? queMoney}) async {
    QuestionsModel questionsModel;
    CollectionReference reference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("quizes");
    try {
      reference
          .doc(quizId)
          .collection("questions")
          .where("prize", isEqualTo: "$queMoney")
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        Map questionData = value.docs.elementAt(random.nextInt(1)).data();
         questionsModel=QuestionsModel(
            question: questionData["question"],
            askTheExpert: questionData["ask_expert"],
            correctAnswer: questionData["correct_answer"],
            optA: questionData["opt_A"],
            optB: questionData["opt_B"],
            optC: questionData["opt_C"],
            optD: questionData["opt_D"],
            prize: questionData["prize"]);
        return questionsModel;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("ERROR IN FETCHING DATA------$e");
    }
  }
}
```

**Repo**
Its just a repository class whcih calls the method of data source

```
class QuestionRepo {
      final QuestionDataSource questionDataSource = QuestionDataSource();
    
      Future<QuestionsModel?> fetchQuestions({String? quizId, int? queMoney})async{
        return await questionDataSource.fetchQuestionModel(queMoney: queMoney,quizId: quizId);
      }
    }
```

**Bloc**
I have created a bloc class in there I used rx dart and try to adding data in stream

```
class QuestionBloc {
      final BehaviorSubject<QuestionsModel?> _questionModel =
          BehaviorSubject<QuestionsModel?>();
    
      Stream<QuestionsModel?> get questionModel => _questionModel;
      QuestionRepo questionRepo = QuestionRepo();
    
      getQuestions({String? quizId, int? queMoney}) async {
        return _questionModel.add(
            await questionRepo.fetchQuestions(quizId: quizId, queMoney: queMoney));
      }
    }
```

**UI**

```
StreamBuilder<QuestionsModel?>(
                  stream: questionBloc.questionModel,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 10),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                      child: Text(
                        snapshot.data?.question ?? "",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: I guess you are missing in  here .stream: 
Stream<QuestionsModel?> get questionModel => _questionModel.stream;

Other than that all looks fine to me..

Comment: I tried this but still have same issue

Comment: Interesting, than I guess you don't even get the question from the server, 

await questionRepo.fetchQuestions(quizId: quizId, queMoney: queMoney)

Print out this statement to you console.log.. and see if you even get back something.